# Javascript object transform with lodash or underscore

Tags: javascript, json, object, underscore.js, lodash

I have an many object with structure of:

```
[{
     n_vId: 1,
     s_vName: 'test',
     d_date: '2016-03-15 00:00:00'
     f_a: 0,
     f_b: 0,
     f_c: 0,
     f_d: 4,
     f_e: 0,
     f_f: 0.1,
     f_g: 0
},
{
     n_vId: 2,
     s_vName: 'test',
     d_date: '2016-03-15 00:15:00'
     f_a: 1,
     f_b: 1,
     f_c: 0,
     f_d: 4,
     f_e: 0,
     f_f: 0.1,
     f_g: 0
}]
```

i want this object transform to

```
a = [
     {
         date: '2016-03-15 00:00:00',
         a: 0
     },
     {
         date: '2016-03-15 00:15:00',
         a: 1
     }
]

b = [
     {
         date: '2016-03-15 00:00:00',
         b: 0
     },
     {
         date: '2016-03-15 00:15:00',
         b: 1
     }
]
...
```

i can transform that. but my process is so complicated i think.
so, would you advice me right process?
now i use lodash but can use underscore or another js modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you don't need Lodash or Underscore, because this is just a `map()` operation, but you can use the `_.map()` function from those libraries if you like.

```js
var objs = [{
  n_vId: 1,
  s_vName: 'test',
  d_date: '2016-03-15 00:00:00',
  f_a: 0,
  f_b: 0,
  f_c: 0,
  f_d: 4,
  f_e: 0,
  f_f: 0.1,
  f_g: 0
}, {
  n_vId: 2,
  s_vName: 'test',
  d_date: '2016-03-15 00:15:00',
  f_a: 1,
  f_b: 1,
  f_c: 0,
  f_d: 4,
  f_e: 0,
  f_f: 0.1,
  f_g: 0
}];

function transform(letter) {
  return _.map(objs, function (obj) {
    var out = {
      date: obj.d_date
    };
    out[letter] = obj['f_' + letter];
    return out;
  });
}

var a = transform('a'),
    b = transform('b'); // etc.

document.getElementById('out').textContent = JSON.stringify({a: a, b: b}, true, '\t');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.6.1/lodash.min.js"></script>

<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: Thumbs up for the transform function: I was going to add the transform function to my answer too, but decided to keep it simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use map:

```
a = data.map(function(i) {
        return {date: i.d_date, a: i.f_a};
    });

b = data.map(function(i) {
        return {date: i.d_date, b: i.f_b};
    });
```

Seems simple enough to me.

Comment: Don't even need a library for this one

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this npm module https://github.com/gabesoft/trans

```
   var trans = require('trans');
   var results = trans(data)
     .mapff('d_date', 'date')
     .mapff('f_a', 'a')
     .pick('date', 'a')
     .value();
```